# Retrieving keys from gurobi variables

Tags: python, gurobi

I am using Python/Gurobi to optimize a problem. I generated variables using:

```
x = f.addVars(DR_dicts.keys(), vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")
```

To display optimal values of decision variables, I use:

```
for v in f.getVars():
    if (abs(v.x) > 0.99):
    print(v.varName, v.x)
```

And I get the solutions below:

```
x[2,37] 1.0
x[2,41] 1.0 etc.
```

How do I access the values [2,37] and [2,41]? I need to use these to calculate some values but retrieving them seems difficult.

Comment: What do you mean? You want the value inside `[ ]`?

Comment: Yes, I want the values inside the []

Answer (score 0):

`Model.getVars()` retrieves all `Var` objects as a Python list. It does not know anything about names or keys. To do what you want, you should save and use the tupledict x.